# JFreeChart Smudging of lines in Candlestick Chart

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

This has reference to JFreeChart rendering of candlestick charts. Below is the code fragment that generates a candle stick chart with JFreeChart.

This code has been tested and has been working for a long time. However, the version of JFreeChart was changed from 1.0.17 to 1.0.19 and the candlestick chart generated with 1.0.19 is showing smudging of the candle objects/lines. When I changed the library back to 1.0.17, the candlestick objects/lines once again becomes clear.

The images with both the libraries are provided below.

I have tried to find the cause of this and have been unsuccessful as yet. Now, the question is, since the code is tested and possibly does not have any error (at least what I can figure or am I missing something?), is the issue with the library? Have anyone faced this problem and has an work around

I shall be rather grateful, if someone has found the reason/solution to this and shared the same.

Please use MS Paint to view the images.

```
try{

        chart=ChartFactory.createCandlestickChart("Candlestick Chart", "Date", "EOD Closing Price", (OHLCDataset)dataset, true);

        plot=(XYPlot)chart.getPlot();
        CandlestickRenderer renderer=new Chart_CandlestickRenderer();//(CandlestickRenderer)plot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLACK);
        renderer.setUpPaint(Color.WHITE);
        renderer.setDownPaint(Color.BLACK);

        //HighLowItemLabelGenerator candleTooltipGenerator=new HighLowItemLabelGenerator(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy"), new DecimalFormat());
        XYToolTipGenerator candleTooltipGenerator=Chart_TooltipProvider.getOHLCTooltipGenerator();
        renderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(candleTooltipGenerator);
        plot.setRenderer(0,renderer);

        //Organize the data to draw Fibbonacci retracements with highs and lows
        DefaultOHLCDataset ohlcDataset=(DefaultOHLCDataset)dataset;
        int dataCount=ohlcDataset.getItemCount(0);
        data=new double[dataCount*2];//for each data item we shall get 2 values, high and low
        for(int i=0;i<dataCount;i++){

            //for each i 2 data values need to be put into the array and adjust the index accordingly
            data[i*2]=ohlcDataset.getHighValue(0, i);
            data[i*2+1]=ohlcDataset.getLowValue(0, i);

        }//for closing

        //If there is only the candlestick to be drawn, return, as the job has been done, draw the Fibonnaci and return
        if(indicators.length==1){

            this.drawFibonnaciRetracement(data, plot);
            retVal=true;
            return retVal;

        }//if closing 

    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();return retVal;}
```

[image: JFreeChart 1.0.17]

[image: JFreeChart 1.0.19]

Comment: if you can post only your frames without desktop background it's better

Comment: See [*How do I create screenshots?*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post)

Comment: The `CandlestickRenderer` [history](http://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/code/HEAD/tree/branches/jfreechart-1.0.x-branch/source/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/CandlestickRenderer.java) is fairly stable.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but give it a try in case some drawing resolution defaults changed in between versions. You can try to wrap the chart in a ChartPanel and set the maximum resolution before things get scaled like this: `chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart); chartPanel.setMaximumDrawHeight(2400); chartPanel.setMaximumDrawWidth(3600);`.

Comment: @xpa1492, tried it, had no impact, lines are still smudged. Has some 2D rendering mechanism changed in 1.0.19 ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting setAntiAlias of the JFreeChart to false.

`JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createCandlestickChart(...);
chart.setAntiAlias(false);`